# Confusion about the output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=1,j=-1;
    if((printf("%d",i))<(printf("%d",j)))
        printf("%d",i);
    else 
        printf("%d",j);
    return 0;
}
```

As `printf()` returns the number of characters successfully printed, the condition will be `if(1<1)` which is false but the if part is executed and the output is `1 -1 1`.  Why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is rather obvious: '1' is one character, '-1' is two. One is less than two.

Answer (score 2):

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) returns the number of **characters** (not just digits) written.

So `printf("%d",-1)` will return `2` not `1`

Similarly `printf("%d",1)` will return `1`

Making the condition in the `if` true.

Answer (score 1):

Because printing j prints "-1", that's two characters. so 1<2 is true.

Comment: thnx ..I got it.I was little bit confused..so thnx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For `-1` number of characters printed is `2` hence if condition is satisfied.